# Codeigniter score ranking

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to get the rank of students based on their scores in a table.  It doesn't seem too complicated but I am not getting it.  Ideally, the function will take a stu_id (integer) and output their rank based on the table that contains columns for 'stu_id', 'stu_nm', and 'stu_scr'.

I have looked at other questions on here but I'm not sure I understand how to apply the answer to my specific problem.  I saw this solution to another thread attempting something similar:

```
SELECT s1.initials, (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM scores AS s2
  WHERE s2.score > s1.score
)+1 AS rank
FROM scores AS s1
```

and tried to apply it to my code which I modified to:

```
$query = $this
                ->db
                ->select('students.stu_id, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM students AS s2 WHERE s2.run_scr > s1.run_scr)
                            +1 AS rank FROM students AS s1')
                ->get('students');
```

Running the code results in this error:

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL         
server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (`students`)' at line 3

SELECT `students`.`stu_id`, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM students AS s2 WHERE s2.run_scr >    
s1.run_scr) +1 AS rank FROM students AS s1 FROM (`students`)

Filename: /home2/uder/public_html/scorer/models/get_score.php

Line Number: 78
```

I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to straighten this out or suggestions of a better solution.

Comment: Your SQL queries has issues I believe.

Comment: your sql query has an extra FROM clause. Can you post the table definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you to write your rank query with active record is wrong try this way

```
$query = $this->db
              ->select('s1.stu_id,
              (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM students AS s2 WHERE s2.run_scr > s1.run_scr) +1 AS `rank`' ,
                      FALSE)
              ->get('students s1');
```

or

```
$query = $this->db
              ->select('s1.stu_id,
              (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM students AS s2 WHERE s2.run_scr > s1.run_scr) +1 AS `rank`' ,
                      FALSE)
              ->from('students s1')
              ->get();
```